# Receiving [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error no TLS on Server

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc, windows-server

I have this python code that I'm trying to execute on an RDC to try and connect to a DB on it:

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import urllib

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(r'Driver=SQL Server;Server=tcp:redacted,1433;Database=redacted;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=0;')
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine_azure = create_engine(conn_str,echo=True)
conn = engine_azure.connect()
```

It is returning this error

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error

I've looked at other questions and people have suggested going here in my registry editor:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS1.0\Client\
```

and enable TLS, although my server doesn't even have TLS. The only thing I'm seeing is SSL. I'm not really familiar on what exactly I need to do from here, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: you define the connection as encrypted so it searches for a patner about transport layer security

Comment: @nbk oh my god. That was it. Thank you!